# The best way to use full-text search in django-filters' FilterSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

My app uses `rest-framework` and `django-filter`. I use this `FilterSet` to provide filtering list of articles (`ModelViewSet`) by `date`:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class ArticleFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='pub_date', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='pub_date', lookup_expr='lte') 

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date']
```

I want to add search box to my app, so I need another filter, that will use full-text search at my `Article` model. Fields I would to search are `title` and `description`. I decided to add `search` field with `method` parameter like that:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

class ArticleFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='pub_date', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='pub_date', lookup_expr='lte')
    search = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_search')

    def filter_search(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'description')).filter(search=value)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date']
```

It works, but I'm not sure that it's the best way of using full-text search filtering. Am I missing something or this approach is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ok for a naive text search where you don't have much text to look into in a small-ish database.

When you get into bigger areas you need to either optimize your db for this or move to a dedicated search engine like Solr or ElasticSearch. Postgres has a [section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/textsearch.html) on full text searching, as does [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).